# How to threshold and BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, threshold

I have read my original image as BufferedImage in Java and then following some operations, I am trying to threshold my image to either high(255) or low(0) but when I save my image, actually I try to overwrite it with new values, the pixels value are not only 0 and 255, some neighbouring values appear, I don't understand why.

**READING MY IMAGE**

```
File input = new File("/../Screenshots/1.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));
            powerspectrum[i][j] = (int) ((c.getRed() * 0.299)
                    + (c.getGreen() * 0.587) + (c.getBlue() * 0.114));
        }
    }
```

**THRESHOLDING MY IMAGE**

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
            if (gradient[i][j] <= upperthreshold
                    && gradient[i][j] >= lowerthreshold)
                spaces[i][j] = 255;
            else
                spaces[i][j] = 0;
            Color gradColor = new Color(spaces[i][j], spaces[i][j],
                    spaces[i][j]);
            image.setRGB(i, j, gradColor.getRGB());
        }
    }
```

**SAVING MY IMAGE**

```
File gradoutput = new File("/../Screenshots/3_GradThresh.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", gradoutput);
```

I don't know how to cut off the other intensity values.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because JPG is a lossy format. When you are saving a JPG to disk, it is doing compression. Try working with bitmap to see if that removes these neighboring gray area values.

Comment: not sure that ImageIO can save bitmaps, but png files should work just as well!

Comment: Matthias got me curious so I looked it up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html). ImageIO supports BMP, PNG, WBMP (wireless bitmap, each pixel is simply black or white), and GIF (as well as JPG). GIF or PNG being good choices from a size perspective.

Comment: @JohnC it works thank you so much. What I did was just  ImageIO.write(image,"bmp", output) and still saved it as jpg.

Comment: @PsiLambdaDelta, you might want to be careful with that if you are doing what I think you are doing (naming a file whose binary contents are in bmp format "xyz.jpg"). I can't think of a specific issue this would cause, but it isn't really good practice (you wouldn't name a .docx .txt even though at the surface they both contain text). Is there a reason you want to use the .jpg filename?

Answer (score 0):

+1 with the jpg compression issue. In image processing, we use PNG (best compression format without loss) or TIFF (worst scenario).

Btw, the methods setRGB/getRGB have terrible performances. The fastest is to modify directly the DataBuffer, but you have to do it for each type of image encoding. An alternative solution (but slower) is to use the Raster. Then you don't have to worry about the encoding.